# VS Code убирает отступ в коде

Tags: visual-studio-code

Вопрос так себе, но сильно меня раздражает. Ранее такого не было, и все отступы присутствовали.

В html коде, при сохранении файла, исчезают отступы в коде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня не пропадают отступы, скорее всего вы что-то в настройках накрутили, или лишних расширений понаставили.

Comment: какого рода расширения могут влиять на это?

Comment: [Formatting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting) - смотрите настройку `html.format.indentInnerHtml`

Comment: "какого рода расширения могут влиять на это?" - любые, касающиеся html или форматирования кода.

Comment: да, уже исправил, спасибо

Comment: Ну, вы бы написали ответ - что вам в итоге помогло. А то люди с теми же вопросами приходят и не знают что делать )  Хотя бы то, что вы написали как комментарий к удалённому уже теперь вопросу-ответу.